# string not recognized as a valid datetime in c# ERROR

Tags: c#, datetime

Even after using `DateTime.ParseExact` I am getting error as

> string not recognized as a valid datetime in c#

Below is my code

```
string strIDODDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Here is full set of code

```
string strRFCsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //string strRFCsDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact("25-09-2019 00:00:00.000", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        //              .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); 

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate))
        {
            Tobj.ID_ODchangeDate = strRFCsDate;
        }
        else
        {
            //Tobj.ID_ODchangeDate = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate);                

            string strIDODDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Tobj.ID_ODchangeDate = strIDODDate;
        }
```

**update**

After debugging, I found out that the format which was coming was with exception was below

`10/28/2021 5:34:35 AM : 10/7/2019 12:00:00 AM 10/28/2021 5:34:35 AM : Error : Dumping  into Table Process : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)`

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. In particular the sample shown in the question does not have information on what is the value code tries to parse. The code shown sets some random property and tries to parse value from another property with unspecified value.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: the `strIDODDate` is `07-10-2019` but coming from db is like `07-10-19`

Comment: Then you will have to use `yy` instead of `yyyy`. Is there no time portion? Please edit your question with a specific example of the incoming string you are trying to parse.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out exactly what you are trying to parse. Put it in your question (unambiguously)

Comment: I debugged and found out that `ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate` was coming in `10/7/2019 12:00:00 AM` format.

Comment: Then there's your answer, your `dd-MM-yyy...` format is wrong, but there is no way we could know that from your question, because the code you have there is right if your date string is formatted right.

Comment: @Andrew: i am trying to handle like this `string strIDODDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");` but still getting the same error

Comment: @hud - and your parseExact format doesn't match the string you are trying to parse, see my answer - we need to know the data you are getting in to tell you why it's failing to give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments and update:

> ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate was coming in 10/7/2019 12:00:00 AM

You are telling `ParseExact` a your format is "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" this means a few things:

1. Your day will ALWAYS have 2 digits, meaning a leading 0 (you have 10)
2. Your month will ALWAYS have 2 digits, meaning a leading 0 (you have 7)
3. Your Year will have 4 digits (you have 2019)
4. Your separator will be '-' (you have /)
5. You will be using the 12 hour clock, including seconds (you have 12:00:00 AM)

The example you gave is not true for 2 and 4 of my list. I expect it won't be true for 1 for the first 9 days of any month, because of this you need to specify a format that doesn't include leading 0s and uses the correct date separators. The format you want is "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" this format tells the parser:

1. The day will have 2 digits if it needs them, no guaranteed leading 0
2. The month will have 2 digits if it needs them, no guaranteed leading 0
3. The year will have 4 digits
4. The separator will be '/'
5. The time will be using the 12 hour clock, including seconds

That means the code will look like this. I pulled the formats out into variables for readability, and turned object.property into a variable to make it run simply in fiddle.

```
string ObjIp_ID_ODchangeDate = "10/7/2019 12:00:00 AM";
string dtFormatIn = "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
string dFormatOut = "dd-MM-yyyy";
string strIDODDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjIp_ID_ODchangeDate, dtFormatIn, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(dFormatOut);
Console.WriteLine(strIDODDate);
```

As you can see, [this works for your case](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eb0PT9).

Answer (score 1):

Unclear from your question, so I'm assuming your incoming date time string is something like `25-09-19 00:00:00.000`

```
var inDateTime = "25-09-19 00:00:00.000";
string parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(inDateTime, "dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(parsedDateTime);
```

Output

> 25-09-2019

UPDATE:

Please review: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

These are the date and time format strings for parsing date times.

It's still unclear if your value is October 7 or July 10... Assuming July 10:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inDateTime = "10/7/2019 12:00:00 AM";
        string parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(inDateTime, "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Console.WriteLine(parsedDateTime);
    }
}
```

Output

> 10-07-2019

See:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YMb82

Comment: I used your answer, but still getting the same error..!!

Comment: What's different in your implementation? Your incoming value must be in a different format

Comment: I debugged and found out that `ObjIp.ID_ODchangeDate` was coming in `10/7/2019 12:00:00 AM` format.

Comment: any idea jonathan ??how to handle this

Comment: I wouldn't use dd/M - chances are if the month doesn't include a leading 0, the day wouldn't either - d/M is likely the better choice.

Comment: Absolutely, but without specific examples from OP impossible to answer 100%